# Solving a question with more unknowns than equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, economics, steady-state

I am not sure if I am thick in the head or not, but I am trying to replicate this paper: https://www.nber.org/papers/w19086.pdf. The equations characterising the equilibrium are given on Page $22$.

Unfortunately it seems as though there are 7 unknowns but only 6 equations (well I am trying to calculate the steady state, so for any time varying variable $X$ which is time varying $X_{t+1} = X_t = X$ and thats how it becomes only 7 unknowns.)

The unknowns are:
$\widetilde{K},\  \widetilde{Q},\ \widetilde{C},\ \widetilde{Y},\tau_k,\tau_l \ and \ L$

I am omitting the time subscripts because I am trying to solve for the steady state, so again, variables are constant through time.

I tried going through the paper again and how we got to the equations but to no avail. I may be missing something super basic here but any help would be great!

Comment: What are the unknowns? $K,Q,C,Y$ with subscripts $t$ and $t+1$? which variable are you referring to as $X$?

Comment: @Dylan Hi, I have edited in some more information into the answers. X is just an example variable, but but it applies to all the variables with the subscript t in the system of equations. I've listed the unknowns above.

Comment: The variables are normalized, so if you want $Q_{t+1}=Q_t$, wouldn't $\widetilde{Q}_{t+1} = \frac{Q_{t+1}}{Q_t} = 1$?

Comment: @Dylan You're a genius. That was quite silly of me! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure it that's really what you want, btw. Since $Q=1$ would imply $Y=L=0$ and some other weird things.

Comment: @Dylan Actually yes, I got too overexcited but the point of this exercise is that $Q_{t+1}/Q_t$ is not a constant. So actually in steady state I believe that $\widetilde{Q_{t+1}}$ is constant, but not $Q_t$

Comment: Seems to me that $\tau_l$ and $\tau_k$ are policy instruments. The definition of equilibrium takes them as given. You then look for $\tau_l$ and $\tau_k$ that solve some objective of the planner/government.

Comment: @Mdoc is right, I forgot to update this when I figured this out, but the series of taxes are taken as given. But an additional question here is that in the transformed series, it seems like I have only 5 endogenous variables and 6 equations now? Since G_0 is exogenously given?